# Predicate Calculus in Prolog-Farmer Wolf Goat Cabbage

Tags: prolog, river-crossing-puzzle

I have this implication from the classic farmer wolf goat cabbage problem in Artificial Intelligence

[image]

The text book says that this rule operates when the farmer and wolf are on the opposite sides of the river.I'm unable to understand the 'if part of the implication'

What does it mean?

Comment: The above rule says: if first parameter is state(X,X,G,C)  which means that farmer and wolf is at the same side (common variable X) then next state-move is of the form state(Y,Y,G,C) where if X=e then Y=w and opposite. So this rule operates when farmer and wolf are in the same side and they both need to go to the opposite side (since this is a valid move).

Comment: @coder Thanks.. why don't you add this as an answer..

Comment: @ techno, Glad to help!!, I didn't add it as an answer since it was a small explanation ,I didn't write any code ...and it fits in comment section so that's the reason...

Comment: @coder, an answer does not require that code be written as long as the answer is fairly complete. Sometimes, words and references to certain terms are all that are needed.

Comment: @lurker, I wrote an answer since as you pointed out it may be better... (I thought my answer should be in comment section but it seems you have right, an answer should be preferred as it is more clear and helpful).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The predicate `move/2` takes  parameters of the form `state/4 in` order to implement the state of problem. In the states the first parameter is used for the farmer, the second for the wolf,third for goat and fourth for cabbage. Every parameter-variable of the state should get either value e (for east) or w (for west).

In order to solve the problem you can define clauses of the form `move(state(F1,W1,G1,C1),state(F2,W2,G2,C2)):-...`  similar to clause in the picture.

The predicate that is shown in the picture is used when both farmer and wolf are in the same side so in the input state the two first variables are common `(state(X,X,G,C))` and want to move in the opposite side so the will go to `state(Y,Y,G,C)` where `opp(X,Y)` is true which means that if X is e then both farmer and wold will move to w and vice versa. The above move is valid since you have implemented previous moves such that farmer and wolf can't be in the same side and simultaneously goat and cabbage are also in the same side (goat would eat cabbage), so the previous sequence of moves since it is valid farmer and wolf can be on the same side and cabbage and goat will be on opposite sides.